# drupal force https on multisite

Tags: .htaccess, https, drupal-7

I have an issue with drupal multisite setup. I have 4 websites in the same drupal installation:
www.example.com/fr, www.example.es, www.example.it, www.example.be/fr
I apply the common https redirection rule in htaccess file :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

all domain that end with "/fr" works great. for the others, domain home page still in http, others urls work great. That my issue.
How to make all domain work (with or without /fr at the end).
Please help me.

Comment: 1. take care that you are not looking at cached results, disable / clear your browsers cache or make a "deep reload".

Comment: 2. make sure that the interpretation of dynamic configuration files is actually enabled for the different hosts (see the `AllowOverride` directive).

Comment: 3. Consider placing such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files. Various reasons why that is the preferred location.

Comment: arkascha, cache are already clear, i always test the rule in private navigation, that still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following
Reference : [d7 multisite](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite-drupal/multi-site-in-subdirectories)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site1
RewriteRule ^ site1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site2
RewriteRule ^ site2/index.php [L]
```

Also :

You can modify the site names in the file sites/site.php

Also update the settings.php file with the credentials of the site.

Also need to update the site url from the host settings

Answer (score 0):

the below solution works for d7 multisits

include the below lines in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

refer - https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/http-to-https-redirects-for-drupal-multisite-setup.606891/